# making over-text div animate and color only the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm having trouble to figure this thing out.

As you can see in the link I've attached there's a div that animates its position over the text. all I want that the red color will be only over the text itself.

Something else I want to do is to make the div go back again and start the animation over and over again.

I hope you can understand what I want. Thank you!

Here's the link to [`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/NV2MR/2/)

Comment: Is this something you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/ce4Ec/

Comment: sorry but unfortunately it is not what i am looking for. thanks for the help! here is some flash i have found that makes it clearer:
http://vebo.co.il/2/banner/293x171_b5.swf
the effect on the first text shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you needed to set the height of #text-light to the height of the parent - in this case the `<p>` element, and also modify your function to reset the css left position first.

```
function start(){
    $("#text-light").css({left: 220}).animate({"left":"-60px"}, 500, start);
}

$("#text-light").height($('p').css('height'));
start();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NV2MR/6/)